# Leaving Burkina Faso

Tags: burkina-faso

On Burkin Faso’s government website, “[Exit conditions](https://www.visaburkina.bf/en/conditions-to-exit-burkina-faso/)” says

> Either a valid passport with a visa issued by the country of
> destination, if applicable, or a national identity card or a
> laissez-passer; either a travel document recognized and accepted in
> the country of destination

How does that affect going from Burkina Faso to a destination allowing "visa on arrival" or one not requiring a visa?  For example, a US citizen going to a Schengen country.

Comment: Key wording in the middle of that phrase: "if applicable".

Comment: The US passport is a "travel document recognized and accepted in the (Schengen zone) country of destination".

Comment: Your probably right.  I interpreted it as a visa document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The US passport is a "travel document recognized and accepted in the (Schengen zone) country of destination". Therefore, you fulfill the exit conditions in this case.